# How to understand the calculation method of target in DDPG algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When DDPG calculates the target, does it have to be multiplied by (1-d)? I don't see this item in DDPG papers, but some DDPG codes have this item.
[target calculation formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7gMH.png)
In other words, why is the value of target equal to the reward r when the state at the next moment is the terminal state?

I checked the explanation of the DDPG algorithm on the Internet, but found no answer related to the above question. So I hope someone can give a reasonable explanation.